# Proving recurrence relation by mathematical induction

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

Consider the following recurrence relation:

> $T(1) = 1$
>
> $T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{2}) + n$

I suspect that $T(n) = n + n\log_2 n$. Using mathematical induction, the base case holds since $T(1) = 1$. The inductive step seems a little complicated: how to prove $T(k+1)$ holds assuming $T(k)$ is true for $k\geq1$?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This recurrence relation doesn't seem to tell you what, say, $T(3)$ is.

Comment: Perhaps induct on powers of $2$? I assume that's closer to what you're looking for since you have $\log_2(n)$ instead of a floor function there (since for $n \ne 2^a$ you'll definitely not get integers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to write your suspected formula is $T\left(2^k\right) = 2^k(k+1)$.

When $k=0$, we have $T(1) = 1$ so that's okay.

Now, assuming the formula holds for $k$, we would have by the recurrence relationship that

\begin{align}
T\left(2^{k+1}\right)
&= 2T\left(2^k\right) + 2^{k+1}
\\&= 2\left(2^k(k+1)\right)+2^{k+1}
\\&= 2^{k+1}(k+1)+2^{k+1}
\\&= 2^{k+1}(k+2)
\end{align}

which agrees with the suspected formula.
So by induction, the suspected formula is correct.

Notice, however, that it is only defined for powers of $2$.
This is because the recurrence relation itself is not defined for other integers.

Comment: Things are clearer now, but could you explain the first line of the inductive step, please? How do you know that $T(2^{k+1})=2T(2^k)+2^{k+1}$?

Comment: This is the given recurrence relationship $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n$.

Comment: Right, so you can use the inductive hypothesis. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to have helped.