# Prove the recurrence relation $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n$ is equal to $n\log(n) + n$ using induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, formal-proofs

**Question**

Given the recurrence relation for the Merge Sort algorithm:

$T(n) = 1$, if $n = 1$

$T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n$, if $n > 1$

Prove by induction that $T(n) = n\log(n) + n$ and hence $O(n\log(n))$

**My solution so far:**

**1. Basis**

$T(1) = 1$

$T(1) = 1\log(1)+1 = 0+1 = 1$

Thus we have established our basis

**2. Induction Hypothesis**

Assume that $T(k) = k\log(k)+k$ is true

**3. Induction Step**

We want to show that $T(k+1) = (k+1)\log(k+1)+(k+1)$

$T(k+1) = 2T((k+1)/2) + (k+1)$

?
?
?

$T(k+1) = (k+1)\log(k+1)+(k+1)$

Comment: $$
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n = 2\left( {\frac{n}{2}\log _2 \left( {\frac{n}{2}} \right) + \frac{n}{2}} \right) + n = (n\log _2 (n) - n\log _2 (2) + n) + n \\= n\log _2 (n) + n
$$

Comment: Needs explanation.  Your recrurrence has $T(n/2)$ where $n/2$ need not be an integer.  What you *can* prove by induction is $T(n) = n\log_2(n)+n$ whenever $n$ is a power of $2$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving recurrence relation by mathematical induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3426774/proving-recurrence-relation-by-mathematical-induction) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24T(n)%3D2T(n%2F2)%2Bn%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24T(n)%3Dn%5Clog(n)%2Bn%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Ainduction&p=1). Note there's also other basically duplicate questions, e.g., [Merge Sort time complexity analysis](/q/54416), [Proving big-o notation with induction](/q/3853392), etc.

Comment: Assume for some $k\in \mathbb Z$ ?